# Certifications for CompSci Grad

Tags: software-industry, software, certification

I'm doing an internship over the summer break and the employer has offered a free MSCE certification (Microsoft solutions expert) that I can take part in. Is it worth while putting this on my CV upon completion? I'll be taking part in it either way so I'll have it anyway. On one hand it may be good to have an extra certification and it won't hurt, but it could also be seen as amateur to potential employers/

Comment: There are few things that would be seen as objectively bad on a resume (by most people) - just look at it like you would anything else you might put on your resume, which is you consider how closely related it is to the job and whether it draws attention away from something that might be more important (e.g. if it would make your resume too long). As with anything else, expect to explain why you did it and why it's on your resume.

Answer (score 3):

Certificates, particularly vendor sponsored ones like a MSCE, are tricky to deal with. A few folks despise them beyond reason, (particularly somewhat rigid, anti-authoritarian types). They will despise you by extension, if they see them on your resume. Other folks (particularly not-technically savvy HR departments) love them, and will put your resume at the bottom of the pile if you don't have one.

You have to use your judgement. If you are applying to a Linux or a Java development shop I would leave it off my resume. You can mention it in the interview if it seems relevant. If you are applying to a Microsoft shop, particularly one where the job description includes system administrative chores, then include it.

Comment: Thanks for that, yea I feel like corporations with an HR department would prefer this. Smaller companies that are more bare bones for lack of a better term wouldn't really care a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It can't look bad. I have a few certificates that are gold standards in the world of development. I had a few people ask me, "So what's that?" And I had to explain the reason behind the certificate. I'd imagine if you had a ridiculous amount of certificates, it would be like the military people with hundreds of medals and pins which look fancy but when you realize it's for things like perfect attendance, it just looks silly.

Now there are some industries that really value certificates. While in most cases big companies aren't really interested in certificates either because they're the HR recruiter and don't know anything about the field, or they know that in many cases certificates are earned through just memorizing and using test preps so they're interested in what sort of knowledge you actually have, not what you remember.

Comment: Thanks for that, I imagine throughout my career I will pick up a number of certifications just from working for that company and not with any huge ambition to gain that certification. I guess 9/10 times it won't hurt and that I should try not to show it off and merely have it as something extra.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it would hurt. Just keep in mind the certificates would be most relevant to the company you're at since it sounds like they like that sort of stuff. Elsewhere, it might not matter as much.